# Can I write a RegEx which matches a pattern, and have part of that pattern be an inverse match?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a RegEx to remove ellipses from a large text.

I need to find a series of two or more dots, possibly with spaces between them, possibly without. The RegEx I'm using is finding instances of full stops which I don't want to remove, so I want part of the RegEx pattern to negate the pattern if it's followed by a particular string.

I've been using this pattern: `re.compile(r'\.[ \.]*\.')`

The problem with this is that there are some legitimate abbreviations in the text which are being caught by this.

Take this text for example:

```
1. Here are ... some . . ellipses..
2. This. . .is ellipsis also.
3. Here is an abbreviation. .i.
```

In the example above, I want my pattern to find only the `...`, `. .`, `..`, and `. . .` in lines 1 and 2. I don't want it to find anything in line 3, however, it will find `. .` in it.

I could update the RegEx to exclude patterns if they're preceded or followed by the letter `i` like this: `re.compile(r'[^i]\.[ \.]*\.'[^i])` but then the pattern won't find the ellipsis in line 2.

Ideally I'd be able to negate a whole sub-string within the pattern so that it won't think `. .` is ellipsis if it's followed by `i.` or preceded by `.i`, however, I haven't been able to find any way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative look ahead and negative look behind:

```
import re

text = """
1. Here are ... some . . ellipses..
2. This. . .is ellipsis also.
3. Here is an abbreviation. .i.
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\.i)\.[ \.]*\.(?!i\.)')
print(pattern.findall(text))   # ['...', '. .', '..', '. . .']
print(pattern.sub('', text))
```

Text after removing `.` sequence:

```
1. Here are  some  ellipses
2. Thisis ellipsis also.
3. Here is an abbreviation. .i.
```

avoid sequence of `.` followed by `i.` you must include another character with `i` to handle this case:

```
     . . .is
```

Comment: `(?<!\.i)\.[ \.]*\.(?!i\.)` to use both look behind and look ahead